# VBA reading two columns inside Excel through loop

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have this code:

```
Dim cityList() 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Test\Cities.xlsx") 
objExcel.Visible = True 

i = 1 
x = 0 

Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" 
ReDim Preserve cityList(x) 
cityList(x) = objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value 
i = i + 1 
x = x + 1 

Loop 

objExcel.Quit
```

I have problem with making this like array with two conditions. My excel contains two columns:
City  Date

```
Mumbai  22.04.2016
Delhi   23.05.2016
Goa     24.06.2016
```

I have managed to read column City and read them one by one, but I need also to read Date and condition is like:

For City = "Mumbai" and Date = "22.04.2016" do something....

I am not very familiar with VBA, but script must be written.

Is anyone can help me how to add also Date inside so he can read both columns?

Thanks upfront

Comment: You might be better using a `Dictionary` object rather than an array if you only have the one instance of any city.  If you can have multiple versions, you might want to consider a 2 dimensional array instead?  Also, this is vbscript rather than VBA (shown where you've had to create the excel application object)

Comment: The problem, that I am using this via Excel, cause I don't know how much members my array will have. I want to have empty array that will have two members, cause my list of the cities and dates will be changed every week Can you send me some examples which will be useful? I have read documentation but is not really clear for, all of them are with predefined size.

Comment: Check my posted answer and comment on it if you think it needs updated any further?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick rewrite of your existing code achieving what I think you're after:

```
Dim cityList(1,0)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Test\Cities.xlsx") 
objExcel.Visible = True 
Set oSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' set the correct sheet name here
iLastRow = oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' determine the last row to look at

For iRow = 1 To iLastRow
    ReDim Preserve cityList(1,iRow-1)                       ' within the loop, extend the array by 1
    cityList(0,UBound(cityList)) = oSheet.Cells(iRow,1)     ' Set the city value
    cityList(1,UBound(cityList)) = oSheet.Cells(iRow,2)     ' Set the date value
Next

' Now you have all the data you can iterate over it like so:
For iLoop = 0 To UBound(cityList,2)
    If cityList(0, iLoop) = "Mumbai" And cityList(1, iLoop) = "22.04.2016" Then
        ' Do whatever you needed to do
    End If
Next

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: I shouldn't enter any real values cause I will never know which city and date my excel will contains :(

Comment: I added those as examples based on your OP.  Presumably at the time you are running the script you DO know what city/date combination you are after, so you would need to include that information in the script and substitute the "Mumbai" with cityName and "22.04.2016" with reqDate or similarly defined variables that are easily understood...

Answer (score 1):

Why all those loops and `redim` ?

```
Dim cityList as variant, lastRow as Long
lastRow = range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
cityList = range("A1:B" & lastrow)
```

Much faster to write and execute

Comment: I have tried this, but it shows my error like end of statement... :( Maybe I am not doing smth good

Answer (score 0):

```
' in your code you can capture date values using offset property

ReDim Preserve cityList(x) 
cityList(x) = objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value 
' = objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value  ' offset property to capture date 
' As Dave said either you can use Dictionary or 2D arrays to store date. . .
i = i + 1
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but in the I am only catching date, and city is skipped?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

```
Dim cityList() 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Test\Cities.xlsx") 
objExcel.Visible = True 
i = 1
x = 0 
y = 0

Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" 
ReDim Preserve cityList(x)
ReDim Preserve cityDate(y)
cityList(x) = objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value
cityDate(y) = objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value

i = i + 1 

x = x + 1 
y = y + 1

Loop 

objExcel.Quit

j = 0

For Each city in cityList

tab = "City"
        datetime = cityDate(j)
        j = j + 1
        count = count + 1
        .....
Next
```

Maybe is not best solution, but is working! Thank you all on suggestions and help!